# Handle Mouse Drag on Screen

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to make tool for capturing screenshot of the mac screen. We have done with taking screenshot of full screen. We want to take screenshot of a particular region on mac screen.
We want this by enabling user to drag on screen for choosing the that particular region for screenshot.

Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: We want this by enabling user to drag on screen for choosing the that particular region for screenshot >>> Tell your users to press Command + Shift + #4.  What else could you do?

Comment: Exactly same we want to add this functionality through our tool that we are going to develop. I need to know the code behind this combination (Command + Shift + #4) so that we could put that code on a button on menubar of our tool.   When user press this button the magnifier comes to choose the area.